# Akka/Scala: onSuccess for multiple asks to different actor

Tags: scala, akka

I'm trying to make an async call to different sub-actors, such as:

```
A ---> B ---> C
        \---> D
```

Actor A sends a request message to Actor B and B send two task messages to C and D, when C and D send the results back, B merge the results up and  send it back to the A.

I was trying to use ask pattern and onSuccess to solve this:

```
class B(fakeInterface: String, subInterface: Array[ActorRef]) extends Actor {

val subCount = subInterface.length
var finishCount = 0

def receive = {
  case reqMsg(msg) =>

    if (subInterface.length == 0){
      sender ! DoneMessage(msg)
    } else {
      implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 minutes)
      val composedFutures = subInterface map { x =>
        (x ? DoItMessage(msg)).mapTo[DoneMessage]
      }

      val allResult = Future.sequence(composedFutures)
      allResult.onSuccess {
        case _ => sender ! DoneMessage(msg)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the code above does not compile at all, I got three error:

```
[error] inferred type arguments [dummy.DoneMessage,Array] do not conform to method sequence's type parameter bounds [A,M[_] <: TraversableOnce[_]]
[error]         val allResult = Future.sequence(composedFutures)
[error]                                ^
[error]  type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Array[scala.concurrent.Future[dummy.DoneMessage]]
[error]  required: M[scala.concurrent.Future[A]]
[error]         val allResult = Future.sequence(composedFutures)
[error]                                         ^
[error]  Cannot construct a collection of type M[A] with elements of type A based on a collection of type M[scala.concurrent.Future[A]].
[error]         val allResult = Future.sequence(composedFutures)
[error]                                        ^
[error] three errors found
```

How can I fix this? Or is there a more proper way to solve this scenario?

Comment: This is not allowed: "allResult.onSuccess {
        case _ => sender ! DoneMessage(msg)
      }" you are closing over this.sender and that will be evaluated to something else by the time that the Future is completed. Please only use the "pipeTo" pattern (akka.pattern.pipeTo) for sending results from Futures to Actors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array` is not a `TraversableOnce`. There is an implicit conversion from `Array` to `WrappedArray` which is a `TraversableOnce`, but by the time the type parameter has been inferred to `Array` it is too late for the implicit conversion. If you replace `Array` with one of the classes from the collections library, e.g. `List` you can get past these compiler errors.

The ask pattern is inefficient because it has to create a fake actor for every request, which creates considerable overhead. It is useful for allowing non-actor code to communicate with actors, but actors themselves should message each other directly. Actor B will have to be stateful so it can keep track of messages from C and D as they come back, but it would make for a better solution.

Comment: Agree with use `List` to solve the issue. One question: as we do not know the location of actors, if you use non-actor code to communicate with actors, can we only talk to local actors? I think a little overhead is acceptable.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner, Thanks for the response! That works as a charm! I have a further question about stateful actor. I was once planning to use this kind of pattern but that actor(B, in our case) seems to have heavy state data. For example: if B get 1000 requests with different context, user_id for example, at one moment, it has to save all of them and keeping maintaining this structure. I'm not sure whether this resource would cause starvation or any other issue. And I believe things will get more difficult when a router is put on this actor. Is there a way out of this in this pattern?

Comment: @stanleyxu2005 Yes, non-actor code can talk to non-local actors. The ask pattern actually creates a fake actor that used for communicating with the actor we are sending the ask to, this allows it to work between actor systems.

Comment: @ChrisKong It could consume a good deal of memory, and you could have issues with memory leaks if the other actors (C and D) don't respond for some reason. The ask pattern has to deal with the same issues, hence the mandatory timeout. Given how the ask pattern takes care of this for you you might want to continue using it, but there would in fact be less overhead if you setup your own stateful actor instead.

Answer (score 1):

`scala.Array` does not inherit from `scala.collection.TraversableOnce` so it cannot be used with `Future.sequence`.  Try using a `List` or `Seq` instead.

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array